# Jquery .find() didn't work in this case

Tags: jquery, css

I have more than one of the `HTML` elements below, on a page

```
<a href='#' class='note-links'>
    <div class='notes'>
        <div class='course_title'><b>{$course_title}</b></div>
        <img src='images/download_file.jpg' class='file' />
        <div class='course_code'>{$course_code}</div>
        <div class='level'>{$course_level} Level</div>
        <div class='price' class='notice'>₦ {$price}</div>
        <div class='opt'><br />
            <a href='' class='edit' id='{$id}'>Edit</a>&nbsp;.
            <a href='' class='delete' id='{$id}'>Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The `div` with `class` `opt` is hidden.
I want on hover of the anchor tag  to make the hidden div visible for only the anchor tag hovered.
I used the jQuery code below

```
$('#menu-display').on('hover', '.note-links', function() {
    $(this).find('.opt').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

When I hover on the anchor tag, nothing shows. However, if I remove the `.find()`, the hidden `div` shows, but for all the other anchor tags not hovered.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `.on('hover' ...` makes me cry ?

Comment: $(this) refers to #menu-display... we need the html for that class too

Comment: @MimiEAM No, `$(this)` refers to `.note-links`.

Comment: @Barmar oh true i missed that

Comment: I think @Matt was partially right, you can wrap a block element in an anchor, but you can not wrap an anchor in another anchor, as it just doesn't make sense to do so, and the browser moves the content, that's why nothing is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS

```
.opt {visibility : hidden}

#menu-display .note-links:hover .opt  {visibility : visible}
```

you don't need jQuery for this, however you **can not wrap an anchor with another anchor** ?

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking, but your answer was already there

Comment: He wants to change the visibility of one element when hovering over a different element.

Comment: @Barmar - yes, but the element to change is inside the element with :hover styles, so that can be done with just CSS. The problem seems to be invalid markup, setting class twice on the same element etc.

Comment: I see how you're doing it now.

Comment: Excellent! I changed the wrapping <a> to <div> and used CSS instead and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `hover` event with `on` method:

> *Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9*: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

```
$('#menu-display').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('.opt').css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('.opt').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}, '.note-links');
```

Comment: It didn't work. If I remomve .find, using the code snippet I posted, it works, but for all the other anchor element not hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
$('#menu-display > .note-links').bind('hover', function() {
    $(this).find('.opt').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.opt').hide();
});
```